# Solution to a pde

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, closed-form

I have a PDE system that I am trying to solve at steady state. When I make the appropriate substitutions, I get an equation of the following form:

$$\frac{1+M}{M}\frac{d^2 M}{d x^2}=1$$
Is there a closed form expression for this? Mathematica finds a nasty solution involving integrals after a lot of thinking. Is this perhaps something that requires nice boundary conditions to solve?

For those that are interested, the system that this originated from is below

---

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2 M}{\partial x^2}-k_{on}R_{tot}M(1-R)+k_{off}R$$
$$\frac{\partial R}{\partial t}=k_{on}R_{tot}M(1-R)-k_{off}R$$

With
  $$\frac{\partial M}{\partial t}(0,t)=\frac{\nu}{R_{tot}}-k_{on}R_{tot}M(1-R)+k_{off}R$$
  $$M(L,t)=R(L,t)= M(x,0)=R(x,0)=0$$

I want to solve this for the steady state, i.e. when $\frac{\partial M}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial R}{\partial t}=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will get a nice expression. First, we write the differential equation as
$$
M''=\frac{M}{M+1}.
$$
Multiplying with $M'$ we find that this is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\bigl((M')^2\bigr)'=\frac{M}{M+1}M'
$$
Integrating, we find  that
$$
\frac{1}{2}(M')^2=M-\log|1+M|+C.
$$
Now you have a separable differential equation, and you will have to integrate it,
$$
\pm\frac{M'}{\sqrt{2(M-\log|1+M|+C)}}=1,
$$
so
$$
\pm \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(M-\log|1+M|+C)}}\,dM=x+\widehat{C}.
$$
I think this is not possible to solve in elementary functions$\dots$

Comment: Thanks for the help, and +1 for that "multiply by $M'$" trick. The variable $M$ represents a concentration, so it's fair to assume the argument of the $log$ will be positive, but I doubt that it will make a difference... might have to see if I can remember some asymptotics...